# Altering Scene.cc to Change Grid Size

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a follow-up question to an earlier one I asked regarding changing grid size. Is there any way to access the Scene.cc file so I can change the hard-coded value of 20x20? I tried to use ls in the directory it's stored in, but all it showed were the .hh files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6689/altering-scene.cc-to-change-grid-size/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You would need to build gazebo from source. Try [these instructions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=install#CompilingFromSource%28Ubuntu%29). Then look in the `gazebo/rendering` folder for Scene.cc

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-07-25**:
I see. Thanks. I'll find an alternate method, then.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-07-25**:
I suppose you could also write a [GUI system plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=system_plugin) to modify the grid size